# Количество товаров в сплывающей корзине opencart 3

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, opencart, opencart3.x

Подскажите как исправить ошибку. Хочу добавить возможность изменять количество товаров после добавления в корзину.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В файл `cart.twig` добавлена разметка:

```
<td>
    <div class="cart_quantity_button">
      
        <a style="font-size:20px; cursor:pointer" class="cart_quantity_down" data-key="{{ product.cart_id }}">-</a>

        <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="text" name="quantity" value="{{ product.quantity }}" autocomplete="off" size="2" readonly>

        <a style="font-size:20px; cursor:pointer" class="cart_quantity_up" data-key="{{ product.cart_id }}">+</a>
      
    </div>
</td>
```

И в файл `common.js` добавлено функцию и слушатели:

```
function updateCart(key, quantity) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/edit',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'key=' + key + '&quantity=' + (typeof (quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#cart > button').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#cart > button').button('reset');

        },
        success: function (data) {

            // Обновление количества товаров в корзине
            $('#cart-total').html(data['total']);

            // Обновление содержимого корзины
            if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
                location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
            } else {

                $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect. Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found (404).');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error (500).');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error. ' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
}

$('.cart_quantity_up').on('click', function () {
    var key = $(this).data('key');
    var quantity = $(this).parent().find('.cart_quantity_input').val();
    quantity++;
    $(this).parent().find('.cart_quantity_input').val(quantity);

    updateCart(key, quantity);
});

$('.cart_quantity_down').on('click', function () {
    var key = $(this).data('key');
    var quantity = $(this).parent().find('.cart_quantity_input').val();
    if (quantity > 1) {
        quantity--;
        $(this).parent().find('.cart_quantity_input').val(quantity);
        updateCart(key, quantity);
    }
});
```

При нажатии на +/- срабатывает событие, количество увеличивается/уменьшается и вызывается функция updateCart() которая должна обновить содержимое корзины. Но метод success не выполняется, так как получаю ошибку "parsererror". (фото прикреплено)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я ошибаюсь, но могу предположить что quantity по какой-то нелепой случайности отправляется не как число, а как строка. Попробуйте проверить ее:

```
if(typeof quantity === 'string'){
    alert('строка')
}else if(!Number.isNaN(quantity)){
    alert('число')
}
```

Comment: quantity - число

Answer (score 0):

приложение в ответ на запрос должно вернуть валидный json-ответ. у вас выбрасывает ошибку, поэтому и json parse error. посмотрите в консоли браузера что приходит в ответе

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос